# Webcam on Sony Vaio on Win 7 problem

Tags: webcam, sony-vaio

Anyone know where I can get a Win 7 32Bit driver for my Web Cam (Vaio VGN-CR11H/B) ? I changed operating system from Chinese Vista to English Win 7

**Update:** Windows 7 will not detect the cam, but I just read the Sony Europe site and it gives me some ideas to try. I can dual boot this Sony laptop:

1. with Chinese Vista, the camera works but IE8 does not work. I cannot read Chinese to fix the Internet access issue, but I can get the computer online and Skype works.
2. When I boot with the new Win 7, IE 8 works great, but the cam doesn't work (mic and speakers work).

Very perplexing problem.

Comment: Hi @Norm, next time please edit your question to respond to answers rather than adding an answer yourself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://genesis.sony-europe.com/instranet/ccil_sony/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=42716&l=en_uk&m=VGN-CR11) on the Sony Europe site suggests windows should find the driver.

Comment: Ivo.  sorry, I looked and the solution for a driver for the Sony VGN-CR11H was not there. I don't understand your comment. Certainly is not helpful to my problem. Norm